# How can I join this two queries,in one?

Tags: rails

I have this 2 queries, and I would like to join them

First query

```
SELECT proveedors.nombre as proveedor, COUNT(productos.id) as distintos
FROM proveedors
INNER JOIN productos ON proveedors.id = productos.proveedor_id
GROUP BY proveedors.id;
```

Second query

```
SELECT proveedors.nombre as proveedor, COUNT(productos.id) as instock
FROM proveedors
INNER JOIN productos ON proveedors.id = productos.proveedor_id
WHERE productos.stock > '0'
GROUP BY proveedors.id;
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Because they have the same `GROUP BY` you can just add the other aggregate function to the select list, like this..

```
SELECT
  proveedors.nombre as proveedor,
  COUNT(productos.id) as distintos,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN productos.stock > '0' THEN productos.id END) as instock
FROM proveedors
INNER JOIN productos ON proveedors.id = productos.proveedor_id
GROUP BY proveedors.id;
```

Or you can use the new `FILTER` clause if your rdbms supports it. PostgreSQL does.

```
SELECT
  proveedors.nombre as proveedor,
  COUNT(productos.id) as distintos,
  COUNT(productos.id) FILTER (WHERE productos.stock > '0') as instock
FROM proveedors
INNER JOIN productos ON proveedors.id = productos.proveedor_id
GROUP BY proveedors.id;
```

You should probably not be single-quoting the 0, but I have no idea what rdbms you're using and what's going on there.

Comment: @NelsonCasanova why is that?

Comment: @NelsonCasanova you could always learn it, =) glad to answer any questions if you try. It's a huge upgrade, and it's free.

Comment: @NelsonCasanova well, SQL Server is pretty good. It's like Number 3 anyway. But there is a big difference between between number 3, and number 1.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, my computer was damaged. I used your code and I got this problem                                                                    ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: sqlite3::sqlexception: near "where": syntax error: SELECT